# Data API PHP Client library Multiple Metrics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Can I request multiple Metrics using the Data API PHP client library?

ex)
**date** for *dimension*, **sessions** and **totalUsers** for *metric* for Data API request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure why not?  Metrics is just an array same as dimensions.

```
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'date',
        ]
    ),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'sessions',
        ]
    ),new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'totalUsers',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);
```

[API Quickstar](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#php)